# Закрыть Form1, открыть Form2

Tags: c#, winforms

Да-да-да, понимаю, тема "заезжая", но сколько я не рыл, ни где толком не объясняется почему все скрывают/показывают форму так:

```
Form2 frm = new Form2();
this.Hide();
frm.Show();
```

Таким способом, активная форма не закрывается, а скрывается, правильно?

Как правильно закрыть `Form1` и открыть `Form2`?

Comment: а зачем вам полностью закрывать форму? опишите задачу подробнее. По умолчанию, первая форма в проекте запускается как приложение и при закрытии формы - закрывается приложение.

Comment: @rdorn, например, ту форму которую хочу закрыть - она мне больше не понадобится, зачем её держать?

Comment: а вариант использования UserControl в размер формы вместо форм не рассматривали?

Comment: @rdorn, приведите, пожалуйста, пример, если не затруднит. Вы сами, вообще, как скрываете форму? :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В проекте WinForms есть два вида форм - главная и дочерние. Разница между ними в том, что главная форма по сути и является приложением, поэтому при ее закрытии происходит выход из приложения.

Одним из решений является скрытие главной формы, вместо закрытия. Этот вариант уже написан в вопросе. Он обычно применяется, когда главная форма так или иначе используется в дальнейшем.

Если первая форма в дальнейшем не используется, то можно использовать 2 варианта:

**1. Правим Program.cs**

По умолчанию содержимое файла Program.cs выглядит так:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

Как вы можете заметить, `Form1` запускается как приложение и, при завершении работы формы, произойдет выход из `Main` и приложения.

Чтобы этого не произошло, можно прописать последовательность запуска форм:

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
Application.Run(new Form2());
Application.Run(new Form3());
```

Тогда при закрытии первой формы, будет вызвана вторая и так до последней.

Недостаток - сложно передавать данные между формами. Да можно определить поля в классе `Program`, конструкторы с параметрами в формах и передавать данные через эти поля и параметры конструкторов, но что делать если нужно вернуться в одну из предыдущих форм? Пилить сложную логику переходов в `Main` - не сама лучшая идея, мягко говоря.

**2. Переходим от форм к контролам**

В WinForms есть замечательный класс [**UserControl**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol(v=vs.110).aspx). Это фактически пустой контрол, который вы можете наполнить любым содержимым как и форму.

После того, как набор таких контролов подготовлен, вам остается только разместить их на форме с параметром `Dock = DockStyle.Fill` и управляя значением свойства `Conrol.Visible`, показывать тот контрол, который вам нужен в данный момент. Если не хотите держать контрол в памяти, ни кто не мешает просто создавать его в нужный момент и отображать, а после использования и переключения на новый контрол, отписаться от событий, вызвать `Dispose()`, удалить все ссылки и отдать его на растерзание сборщику мусора. Только выигрыш от этого невелик, особенно если вдруг надумаете снова его показать.

---

Забыл написать про еще один недостаток переключения между формами через `Main`. Каждая новая форма будет открываться немного в другом месте, может для защиты от программ-автокликеров это и хорошо, но меня, как пользователя, такое поведение раздражает, и думаю что не только меня.

---

> Ещё можно не передавать форму в Application.Run и запустить его без параметров. Тогда даже закрытие всех форм не приведёт к закрытию приложения. Чтобы выйти окончательно необходимо будет вызвать Application.Exit – Lunar Whisper

Тоже хороший вариант, если необходимо использовать разные формы в процессе работы.

Comment: Спасибо большое за развернутый ответ.

Comment: Ещё можно не передавать форму в `Application.Run` и запустить его без параметров. Тогда даже закрытие всех форм не приведёт к закрытию приложения. Чтобы выйти окончательно необходимо будет вызвать `Application.Exit`

Comment: @LunarWhisper спасибо, надо попробовать, тогда и обновлю ответ. За одно некоторые свои ляпы поправлю. Правда проблема со смещением последующих форм останется, можно конечно впилить туда логику копирования Location, но вариант с контролами лично мне больше нравится

Answer (score 0):

```
        using System.Threading;
        Thread f1f2;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                    this.Close();
                    f1f2 = new Thread(open);
                    f1f2.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                    f1f2.Start();
         
    }
    public void open(object obj)
    {
        Application.Run(new Form2());
    }
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score -1):

```
this.Close(); 
frm.Show();
```

Так вроде

Comment: Так программа закрывается сразу же.

Comment: будет работать только с дочерними формами, при закрытии главной, закроется приложение.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?