# как правильно создать несколько похожих форм?

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть несколько похожих форм (размер, бэкграунд, 1 кнопка), на каждую из которых добавляются различные элементы: на одну - текстбокс, на другую - картинки, на третью - еще несколько кнопок. Как это правильно организовать?

Comment: В чем собственно проблема? Можно сделать Copy/Paste

Comment: Пока я сделала одну форму с фоном и кнопкой и от нее наследуют остальные. Но в идеале было бы задать что-то типа класса - чтоб на форме были все необходимые компоненты, а вызывались только некоторые при каждой инициализации

Comment: ну вы можете прятать ненужные элементы `Form.Visible = false`. Возможных решений много.

Comment: Как на счет именованного конструктора? На форме размещаются все элементы интерфейса, а вызываемый конструктор определяет , что отобразить на созданной форме?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/574140/198316 пункт 2 посмотрите. Наследование вполне рабочий вариант, если вы конечно правильно выделили общий функционал. Вариант с наследованием применим к варианту по ссылке.

Answer (score 1):

Как, вариант- это разместить на форме все элементы в скрытом состоянии.
В классе формы нужно реализовать именованные конструкторы(Фабричный метод), которые будут создавать форму с нужным функционалом.

Comment: тут скорее нужно кастомное свойство, которое позволит выбрать пресет, активирующий нужные элементы, фабрики ИМХО немного для другого. Но тоже рабочий вариант.