# Переключение между формами C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Доброго времени суток, уважаемое комьюнити. У меня такой вопрос. Как лучше всего настроить переключение между формами в C#? Например, у меня есть главная форма, которая открывается при запуске программы. Потом по нажатию на кнопку я хочу, чтобы эта форма закрывалась, а другая форма появлялась на экране. Я сделал такую штуку:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Statistics().Show(); //Создается форма Statistics и выводится на экран
        this.Hide(); //А эта форма скрывается
    }
```

Но я не уверен, в том что это оптимальное решение. Заранее благодарю за ответы.

Comment: Реально проблема только то, что вы не закрываете основную форму, а прячете ее. А процесс завершается только при закрытии основной. Догадываетесь, к чему это приведет? Лучше закрывать основную форму, или не трогать ее вовсе.

Comment: возможно дубль https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/574122/198316. В любом случае там я уже подробно расписал возможные варианты

Comment: Само же по себе новое создание формы всякий раз - это обычно не страшно. Ну если страшно - тогда применяйте синглтон - а заранее всего не предвидишь. Единственное, не стоит new и Show одной строкой - это неудобно, если перед Show придется делать с формой еще что-то.

Comment: @rdorn Окей, можно использовать UseControl. Я с этим классом раньше не работал. Будет ли его удобно использовать, если мне надо постоянно переключаться между формами? То есть мне постоянно надо убирать и выводить на экран главную форму и другие формы. Например, я запускаю программу, появляется главная форма. Теперь мне надо преключиться с главной формы на вторую. Потом со второй обратно на главную, а с главной на третью. А потом снова с третьей на главную, и с нее на вторую. И так далее. Будет ли это удобно?

Comment: @AlexanderPozdniakov да, разумеется, т.к. при этом не придется создавать новую форму и перечитвать/пересчитывать данные. Просто меняете видимость контролов. Те которые невидимы - продолжают работать, только не отображаются.

Comment: @rdorn Понял, спасибо.

Comment: @Rou1997 Я тоже думал, что закрытие форм, это выход. Но во-первых, нельзя закрывать главную форму. А во-вторых, как быть обратным переходом со второй формы на главную?