# Событие click у user control

Tags: c#, winforms

Как при помощи `user control` вызвать другую форму.
Есть `Form1` с `user_control1` и есть `Form2`. Как показать `Form2` по щелчку по `user_control1`.
**P.S.** `user_control1` добавляется динамически на форму.

Comment: Посмотрите [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/574122/213987) да и вообще в [поиске были](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+Form1+Form2+%09is%3Aquestion)?

Comment: Что значит показать? Она свернута у вас и её надо развернуть или надо создать новую форму типа форм2 и показать?

Comment: @tym32167 нужно создать новый экземпляр Form2 и показать его. Только по клику на user control. Когда я вписываю в обработчик Click user control-а код вызова новой формы - у меня он не срабатывает на Form1

Comment: `userControl.Click += (sender, args)=>new Form2().Show();` пробовали?

Comment: @tym32167 нет. Как это вообще в коде оформить?  Где это писать (в коде usrtControl-а или формы) ?

Comment: можете в юзерконтроле в конструторе подписаться. Можете подписаться там, где юзер контрол создаете. Это уже как вам удобней